# Слайд галерея для сайта помощь найти проблему!

Tags: javascript, html, css3

Здраствуйте! Нашел простенькую слайд галерею. Но когда хочу добавить новое изображение, оно не отображается, и никак не реагирует. Помогите разобраться, как сюда добавить новое фото и что где нужно изменить, а то криво получается. Спасибо. Код HTML ,и CSS ,и скрипт прикреплены.

```
<body>
<div id="slider">
  <div id="mask">
    <ul id="image_container">
      <li><img src="images/bird.jpg" alt="foto" /></li>
      <li><img src="images/red_bird.jpg" alt="foto" /></li>
      <li><img src="images/spring.jpg" alt="foto" /></li>
      <li><img src="images/winter.jpg" alt="foto" /></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <img src="resources/glass.png" id="glass">
  <ul id="dots">
      <li class="button1" onClick="changeImage(1)" ></li>
      <li class="button2" onClick="changeImage(2)" ></li>
      <li class="button3" onClick="changeImage(3)" ></li>
      <li class="button4" onClick="changeImage(4)" ></li>
  </ul>
  <img src="resources/fleche-gauche.png" id="fleche_gauche" class="fleche" onClick="prevImage()" >
  <img src="resources/fleche-droite.png" id="fleche_droite" class="fleche" onClick="nextImage()" >
</div>
<script>
  var secDuration = 5;
  var image = 1;
  var maxImages = 4;
  var slider = document.getElementById('slider');
  var timeout

  function changeImage(requiredImage) {

    if (!requiredImage && requiredImage != 0){ 
      if(image < maxImages){
        image++;
      }
      else{
        image = 1;
      }
    }
    else{ 
      if(requiredImage > maxImages){
        image = 1;
      }
      else if(requiredImage < 1){ 
        image = maxImages;
      }
      else{
        image = requiredImage; 
      }
    }
    slider.className = "image"+image;

    clearTimeout(timeout)
    timeout = setTimeout("changeImage()",secDuration*1000);
  }

  function nextImage(){
    changeImage(image+1);
  }
  function prevImage(){
    changeImage(image-1);
  }

  changeImage(1);
</script>
```

```
*{        
padding:0;
margin:0;
list-style-type:none;
}

#slider{
background:url('resources/background.png');
width:960px;
height:370px;
margin:50px auto;
position:relative;
}

#mask{
width:100%;
height:100%;
position:absolute;
overflow:hidden;
}

.fleche{
position:absolute;
top:145px;
cursor:pointer;
}

#fleche_gauche{
left:-17px;
}

#fleche_droite{
right: -17px;
}

#image_container{
position:absolute;
width:400%;
height:100%;
/* Chrome */ 
-webkit-transition-property:all;
-webkit-transition-duration:1s;
/* Firefox */ 
-moz-transition-property:all;
-moz-transition-duration:1s;
/* Opera */ 
transition-property:all;
transition-duration:1s;
}

.image1 #image_container{
left:0;
}

.image2 #image_container{
left:-100%;
}

.image3 #image_container{
left:-200%;
}

.image4 #image_container{
left:-300%;
}

#image_container li{
float:left;
}

#encart{
position:absolute;
top:-15px;
left:200px;
background:url('resources/text.png');
width:328px;
height:396px;
}

#bouton{
position:relative;
width:244px;
height:55px;
margin: 300px 0px 0px 40px;
cursor:pointer;
}

#dots{
position:absolute;
width:130px;
height:15px;
left:425px;
bottom:-25px;
}

#dots li{
float:left;
margin: 0px 2px;
width:12px;
height:12px;
background: url('resources/empty-dot.png');
cursor:pointer;
}

#dots li:hover{
background: url('resources/selected-dot.png');
}

.image1 #dots li.button1, .image2 #dots li.button2, .image3 #dots             li.button3, .image4 #dots li.button4{
background: url('resources/selected-dot.png');
cursor:normal;
}

#glass{
position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Очень кривой скрипт. Не рекомендовал бы его использовать.

Есть огромное множество отличных слайдеров на jQuery, например [WOWSlider](https://plugins.jquery.com/WOWSlider/)

Можно так же найти без jQuery, но таких меньше.